# Does Messenger API (or any other facebook api) include video calling?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

After reviewing the messenger API, it doesn't seem you can programatically start, end or manage video calls.

I've searched quite a bit but when searching for "video call" or "cam", "camera" etc, I get a lot of noise results around SENDING videos as attachments. I need to allow video calls to a select set of people based on their availability.

Is starting the call, and tracking details of the call, possible from any facebook api?

Comment: No it is not possible

Comment: Thanks @WizKid .